# What should an array of pointers point to when dynamically allocating it?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

The code sometimes, and other times it completely crashes on me. I suspect that this is happening because my array of pointers is probably pointing to some random place in memory. I believe that setting a place so that all of the pointer elements points to a consist place.

When reading from a file with a small number of words it works perfectly fine. However, as soon I read form a huge file I get a lot of trash into my program. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class orignialData {
    char* data;

public:

    void setData(char* s) { data = strdup(s);}
    char* getData() const {return data;}
};

class dataClass {
    orignialData** W_;
    unsigned int capacity_;   // max number of words Dictionary can hold
    unsigned int numberOfWordsInDictionary_;

public:

    dataClass(char* filename);

    void addData();
    void viewAll() const;
    void reSize();
};

void dataClass::reSize() {
    static int i = 0;
    W_[i] = new orignialData;

    if (i == 7) {
        cout << "Dictionary is now the size of: " << i << endl;
    }

    i++;
}

dataClass::dataClass(char* filename) {
    fstream file;
    char buff[30];
    capacity_ = 8;

    file.open(filename, ios::in);

    if(file.fail()) {
        cout << "There was an error oppennig the file....\n";
    }

    W_ = new orignialData*[capacity_];

    while (file >> buff) {
        static int i = 0;


        reSize();

        W_[i] -> setData(buff);
        i++;
    }



    file.close();
};

void dataClass::viewAll() const {

    cout << W_[0] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[1] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[2] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[3] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[4] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[5] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[6] -> getData() << endl;
    cout << W_[7] -> getData() << endl;



}


int main() {

    dataClass dic("simple");

    cout << "calling the view all funcion....\n";
    dic.viewAll();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `prog.cpp:85:27: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to ‘char*’`

Comment: Why is `i` static in `resize`? It's hard to figure out what your intention was here, but it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: This program seems to have been written in the most fragile and non-reusable way possible. It assumes `simple` is a readable / existing file containing exactly 8 words of at most 29 characters each. If any of those assumptions does not hold, it exhibits undefined behavior (accessing array elements out of bounds).

Comment: As mentioned, your code only allows eight words. Of course if you give it a huge file it will break. Is this some assignment of manual memory handling, or “use C++ like it was C” or something else? Because there’s `std::string`, `std::vector` etc that normally would be used. There’s also a memory leak in `orignialData`

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing i to 0 inside the while loop, the array will only fill one element, the remaining elements will only have memory addresses. Initialize i to 0 before entering the while loop and only incriment the i inside.